# Excel freezes after first Sub

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell, freeze

I have the following Code that should give me for every User a copy to another Worksheet. As the input data for every varies, I have to define the ranges with the appearances of Usernames. Unfortunately, the last one does not work (Where "Total" stands for the last row containing data)and if comment the last one out, Excel freezes after the first Sub SelectRange() although they work individually. Can someone help here?

Here is the Code:

```
Sub Main()
    Call SelectRangeUser1
    Call SelectRangeUser2
    Call SelectRangeUser3
    Call SelectRangeUser4
    Call SelectRangeUser5
    Call SelectRangeUser6
    Call SelectRangeUser7
    Call SelectRangeUser8
   
End Sub




Sub SelectRangeUser1()
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim endCell As Range
    Dim searchStringStart As String
    Dim searchStringEnd As String
    Dim searchStringStop As String
    Dim currentCell As Range
   
    searchStringStart = "User1" 
    searchStringEnd = "User2" 
    searchStringStop = "User2" 
   
    ' search for the start string in the active sheet
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringStart Then
            Set startCell = currentCell
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if start string is found, search for the end or stop string
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.Range(startCell, ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringEnd Or currentCell.Value = searchStringStop Then
            Set endCell = currentCell.Offset(-2) ' offset end cell by two rows
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if end or stop string is found, select the range from start to end
    If Not endCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim newSheet As Worksheet
        Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add
        newSheet.Name = "User1"
        Dim newRange As Range
        Set newRange = Range(startCell, endCell).Resize(, 11)
        newRange.Copy newSheet.Range("A1")
        newRange.Name = "User1"
    End If
End Sub


Sub SelectRangeUser2()
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim endCell As Range
    Dim searchStringStart As String
    Dim searchStringEnd As String
    Dim searchStringStop As String
    Dim currentCell As Range
   
    searchStringStart = "User2" 
    searchStringEnd = "User3" 
    searchStringStop = "User3" 
   
    ' search for the start string in the active sheet
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringStart Then
            Set startCell = currentCell
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if start string is found, search for the end or stop string
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.Range(startCell, ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringEnd Or currentCell.Value = searchStringStop Then
            Set endCell = currentCell.Offset(-2) ' offset end cell by two rows
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if end or stop string is found, select the range from start to end
    If Not endCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim newSheet As Worksheet
        Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add
        newSheet.Name = "User2"
        Dim newRange As Range
        Set newRange = Range(startCell, endCell).Resize(, 11)
        newRange.Copy newSheet.Range("A1")
        newRange.Name = "User2"
    End If
End Sub



Sub SelectRangeUser3()
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim endCell As Range
    Dim searchStringStart As String
    Dim searchStringEnd As String
    Dim searchStringStop As String
    Dim currentCell As Range

    searchStringStart = "User3" 
    searchStringEnd = "User4"
    searchStringStop = "User4"

    ' search for the start string in the active sheet
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringStart Then
            Set startCell = currentCell
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if start string is found, search for the end or stop string
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.Range(startCell, ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringEnd Or currentCell.Value = searchStringStop Then
            Set endCell = currentCell.Offset(-2) ' offset end cell by two rows
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if end or stop string is found, select the range from start to end
    If Not endCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim newSheet As Worksheet
        Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add
        newSheet.Name = "User3"
        Dim newRange As Range
        Set newRange = Range(startCell, endCell).Resize(, 11)
        newRange.Copy newSheet.Range("A1")
        newRange.Name = "User3"
    End If
End Sub



Sub SelectRangeUser4()
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim endCell As Range
    Dim searchStringStart As String
    Dim searchStringEnd As String
    Dim searchStringStop As String
    Dim currentCell As Range

    searchStringStart = "User4" 
    searchStringEnd = "User5" 
    searchStringStop = "User5" 
   
    ' search for the start string in the active sheet
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringStart Then
            Set startCell = currentCell
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if start string is found, search for the end or stop string
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.Range(startCell, ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringEnd Or currentCell.Value = searchStringStop Then
            Set endCell = currentCell.Offset(-2) ' offset end cell by two rows
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if end or stop string is found, select the range from start to end
    If Not endCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim newSheet As Worksheet
        Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add
        newSheet.Name = "User4"
        Dim newRange As Range
        Set newRange = Range(startCell, endCell).Resize(, 11)
        newRange.Copy newSheet.Range("A1")
        newRange.Name = "User4"
    End If
End Sub



Sub SelectRangeUser5()
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim endCell As Range
    Dim searchStringStart As String
    Dim searchStringEnd As String
    Dim searchStringStop As String
    Dim currentCell As Range

    searchStringStart = "User5"
    searchStringEnd = "User6" 
    searchStringStop = "User6" 
   
    ' search for the start string in the active sheet
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringStart Then
            Set startCell = currentCell
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if start string is found, search for the end or stop string
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.Range(startCell, ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringEnd Or currentCell.Value = searchStringStop Then
            Set endCell = currentCell.Offset(-2) ' offset end cell by two rows
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if end or stop string is found, select the range from start to end
    If Not endCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim newSheet As Worksheet
        Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add
        newSheet.Name = "User5"
        Dim newRange As Range
        Set newRange = Range(startCell, endCell).Resize(, 11)
        newRange.Copy newSheet.Range("A1")
        newRange.Name = "User5"
    End If
End Sub



Sub SelectRangeUser6()
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim endCell As Range
    Dim searchStringStart As String
    Dim searchStringEnd As String
    Dim searchStringStop As String
    Dim currentCell As Range
     
    searchStringStart = "User6" 
    searchStringEnd = "User7" 
    searchStringStop = "User7" 
   
    ' search for the start string in the active sheet
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringStart Then
            Set startCell = currentCell
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if start string is found, search for the end or stop string
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.Range(startCell, ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringEnd Or currentCell.Value = searchStringStop Then
            Set endCell = currentCell.Offset(-2) ' offset end cell by two rows
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if end or stop string is found, select the range from start to end
    If Not endCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim newSheet As Worksheet
        Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add
        newSheet.Name = "User6"
        Dim newRange As Range
        Set newRange = Range(startCell, endCell).Resize(, 11)
        newRange.Copy newSheet.Range("A1")
        newRange.Name = "User6"
    End If
End Sub



Sub SelectRangeUser7()
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim endCell As Range
    Dim searchStringStart As String
    Dim searchStringEnd As String
    Dim searchStringStop As String
    Dim currentCell As Range
    Dim startStringCount As Integer ' counter for the number of times the start string is found

    searchStringStart = "User7" ' change this to your specific start string
    searchStringEnd = "User8" ' change this to your specific end string
    searchStringStop = "User8" ' change this to your specific stop string
    startStringCount = 0 ' initialize start string count to zero
   
    ' search for the start string in the active sheet
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringStart Then
            startStringCount = startStringCount + 1 ' increment start string count
            If startStringCount = 2 Then ' if this is the second appearance of the start string
                Set startCell = currentCell
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if start string is found, search for the end or stop string
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.Range(startCell, ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringEnd Or currentCell.Value = searchStringStop Then
            Set endCell = currentCell.Offset(-2) ' offset end cell by two rows
            Exit For
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if end or stop string is found, select the range from start to end
    If Not endCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim newSheet As Worksheet
        Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add ' create a new worksheet
        newSheet.Name = "User7" ' assign a name to the new worksheet
        Dim newRange As Range
        Set newRange = Range(startCell, endCell).Resize(, 11) ' resize the selected range to include columns A to K
        newRange.Copy newSheet.Range("A1") ' copy the selected range to the new worksheet
        newRange.Name = "User7" ' assign a name to the selected range
    End If
End Sub


Sub SelectRangeUser8()
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim endCell As Range
    Dim searchStringStart As String
    Dim searchStringEnd As String
    Dim searchStringStop As String
    Dim currentCell As Range
    Dim lastStartCell As Range ' variable to store the last cell where the start string was found
     
    searchStringStart = "User8" 
    searchStringEnd = "Total"
    searchStringStop = "Total"
   
    ' search for the start string in the active sheet
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If currentCell.Value = searchStringStart Then
            Set lastStartCell = currentCell ' update the last cell where the start string was found
            If startCell Is Nothing Then
                Set startCell = currentCell
            End If
        End If
    Next currentCell
   
    ' if start string is found, search for the end or stop string after the last cell where the start string was found
    If Not lastStartCell Is Nothing Then
        For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.Range(lastStartCell.Offset(1), ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
            If currentCell.Value = searchStringEnd Or currentCell.Value = searchStringStop Then
                Set endCell = currentCell.Offset(-2) ' offset end cell by two rows
            End If
        Next currentCell
    End If
   
    ' if end or stop string is found, select the range from start to end
    If Not endCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim newSheet As Worksheet
        Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add ' create a new worksheet
        newSheet.Name = "User8" ' assign a name to the new worksheet
        Dim newRange As Range
        Set newRange = Range(startCell, endCell).Resize(, 11) ' resize the selected range to include columns A to K
        newRange.Copy newSheet.Range("A1") ' copy the selected range to the new worksheet
        newRange.Name = "User8" ' assign a name to the selected range
    End If
End Sub
```

As already explained, I tried to set up a routine to identify changing ranges from an input and copying it to a new Worksheet in the same Workbook.

Comment: Looks like you are repeating the same code 8 times. Make a sub with arguments and pass those arguments to your variables. check [this](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/macros/arguments.htm#:~:text=VBA%20allows%20you%20to%20pass,is%20very%20important%20to%20make.&text=In%20VBA%20all%20objects%20are%20passed%20by%20reference.)

Comment: Yes that's true, basically it's the same code. I'll check the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure whether to post this as it doesn't answer why your code is freezing - it does show a better and shorter way to search for all users providing there's no gaps in the numbering.
If there are gaps you'd have to change the username look up - maybe a unique list of names in your data and search through that (UNIQUE formula if you've got 365).

This doesn't check for existing worksheets with the same name, so maybe put an error handler in for that.

```
Sub Extract()

    Dim SearchString As String
    SearchString = "User"
    
    Dim UserNum As Long
    UserNum = 1
    
    'Any range in this block that starts with . is refering to column A
    'in Sheet1 of the workbook containing this code.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
    
        Dim foundStart As Range
        Dim foundEnd As Range
        Do
            'Find the first and last occurrence of the user name (xlNext, xlPrevious).
            'Note - user names start on row 2, with heading on row 1.
            'The search starts AFTER the first cell ( .Cells(1,1) )
            Set foundStart = .Find(SearchString & UserNum, .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext)
            Set foundEnd = .Find(SearchString & UserNum, .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            
            'If the range is found then create a new sheet and copy the data to it.
            If Not foundStart Is Nothing Then
                Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
                Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
                wrkSht.Name = SearchString & UserNum
                
                .Range(foundStart, foundEnd).Resize(, 11).Copy _
                    Destination:=wrkSht.Cells(1, 1)
            End If
            
            'Increase the user name by 1 and search again.
            UserNum = UserNum + 1
             
        Loop While Not foundStart Is Nothing
    End With

End Sub
```

For specific user names you could use the code below.  Would be better to pass the user names as an argument though.

```
Sub Extract()

    Dim UsrNames As Variant
    UsrNames = Array("Me", "You", "Someone else")
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
        Dim UsrName As Variant
        For Each UsrName In UsrNames
            
            Dim foundStart As Range
            Dim foundEnd As Range
            'Find the first and last occurrence of the user name (xlNext, xlPrevious).
            'Note - user names start on row 2, with heading on row 1.
            'The search starts AFTER the first cell ( .Cells(1,1) )
            Set foundStart = .Find(UsrName, .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext)
            Set foundEnd = .Find(UsrName, .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            
            'If the range is found then create a new sheet and copy the data to it.
            If Not foundStart Is Nothing Then
                Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
                Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
                wrkSht.Name = UsrName
                
                .Range(foundStart, foundEnd).Resize(, 11).Copy _
                    Destination:=wrkSht.Cells(1, 1)
            End If
            
        Next UsrName
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Darren, this would definitely help but I replaced the names of colleagues with User1,2,3 etc. for the post in here. So there are different names instead of the Users

Comment: Have updated the code.